# emacs regex not matching as expected

Tags: regex, emacs

I'm trying to match the following text:

```
void foo( int xxx,
int const & xxx,
```

With the regex:

```
\(\s-+\)[^\s-]+,$
```

IE: match whitespace, followed by non-whitespace, followed by a single comma at the end of the line

Expected matches:

```
[space]xxx, (line 1)
[space]xxx, (line 2)
```

Actual matches:

```
[space]foo( int xxx, (line 1)
[space]& xxx, (line 2)
```

Why is emacs matching the spaces midstring even though I've specified 'no space'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character alternative, `[^\s-]` matches anything other than `\`, `s`, and `-`.

See "`[ ... ]`" in `C-h i g (elisp) Regexp Special RET`.

Instead of that, you want to use `\S-` (upper-case) as the inverse of `\s-`
(`C-h i g (elisp) Regexp Backslash RET`).

Or, if you still want/need a character alternative, use character classes
(`C-h i g (elisp) Char Classes RET`).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have not anchored the regexp to the beginning of the line. So in your two later cases:

```
[space]foo([space]int[space]xxx, (line 1)
[space]&[space]xxx, (line 2)
```

It simply matches `[space]xxx,`.

Try `^\(\s-+\)[^\s-]+,$` (or, when written as an Emacs Lisp string: `"^\\(\\s-+\\)[^\\s-]+,$"`)